# AngularJS & Jasmine: Testing that a method on the scope was called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have this code in a directive

```
function createChartOptions(chartData, panelIndex, legendHeights) {

                    if (some condition) {
                        scope.setCurrentBoundary({ min: chartOptions.xAxis[0].min, max: chartOptions.xAxis[0].max, isDatetimeAxis: chartOptions.xAxis[0].type === "datetime" });
                    }
   ...
}
```

I want to test whether `scope.setCurrentBoundary` is called, so I wrote this test

```
it('Should set current boundary', function () {
                expect(scope.setCurrentBoundary).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ min: 1380589200000, max: 1398733200000, isDatetimeAxis: true });
            });
```

Problem is that this gives me this error

```
Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined.
```

I understand why this is happening but I don't know what the proper way is to test that the particular if statement in my code is being executed and that then the `scope.setCurrentBoundary` method is being called with those particular arguments.  What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't configured the spy.

```
spyOn(scope, 'setCurrentBoundary').andCallThrough();
```

or if you're on jasmine 2.0

```
spyOn(scope, 'setCurrentBoundary').and.callThrough();
```

This must be done before you try to do expectations on the spy (and obviously after the controller is initialized), I prefer doing this in a `beforeEach` block.

Comment: I tried that but I got this error: "setCurrentBoundary() method does not exist
Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined."

Comment: +1 for helping though.  If you know why I get this error that would be helpful.

Comment: Did you initialize the controller before trying to configure the spy? Maybe you could edit your question with some more code from your test? Especially the bit where the controller/scope is set up and where the spy is configured?